# How can I calculate number of current VC's in Navigation stack?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

Any ideas? I want to know number of MyViewControllers.

Comment: Look at the docs for `UINavigationController`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said "number of MyViewControllers" not number of viewControllers, so I assume you want to know how many of the viewControllers in the stack are instances of your own custom subclass. That's where the method [anyObject isKindOfClass] comes in. This snippet should help:

```
NSArray *viewControllerStack = [[self navigationController] viewControllers];
NSUInteger result = 0;
for(UIViewController *vc in viewControllerStack) {
    if([vc isKindOfClass:[MyViewController class]] result++;
}
```

Is this what you're looking for?

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
int count = [[navigationController viewControllers] count];
NSLog(@"controllers : %@", [navigationController viewControllers]);
NSLog(@"count : %d", count);
```

`[navigationController viewControllers]` which returns an array of controllers in navigation stack. using this array you can get the count of controllers.

Comment: `[navigationController viewControllers]` which returns an array of controllers in navigation stack. using this array you can get the count of controllers.

Comment: Put it in the post. A code-only answer is incomplete.